# what is wrong with my code here: how to use class and instance

Tags: python, class

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        n = len(nums)
        for i in range(n - 1):
            for j in range(i + 1, n):
                if nums[i] + nums[j] == target:
                    return [i, j]
        return []  # No solution found
o = [2, 6, 7, 5, 3]
m = 9
Re = Solution(o,m)
```

it returned the error:

```
Solution() takes no arguments
```

Comment: it's going to be hard to help without properly formatting your code

Comment: If you want `twoSum` to be called, you'll need to tell it that somehow.

Comment: You have to define a constructor for the class which takes the arguments.

Comment: Try `s = Solution()` then `s.twoSum(o,m)`

Answer (score 3):

This has no reason to be a class; a standalone function will do:

```py
def twoSum(nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    n = len(nums)
    for i in range(n - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            if nums[i] + nums[j] == target:
                return [i, j]
    return []  # No solution found
o = [2, 6, 7, 5, 3]
m = 9
Re = twoSum(o,m)
```

If you insist on using a class, you need to first create the instance, then call the method on it:

```py
Re = Solution().twoSum(o,m)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That works. Yeah I agree. There is no point to add class here.

Comment: you could also make it a Class Method if you really wanted it to be associated with a class. that said i agree with your sentiment that this should just be a free function.